# Regular expressions doesn't change any text in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this code to replace every number (and point) and replace it by `<b>and the text</b>`

```
<?

function reem2($cadena) {

   $buscarRegex = array('/^([0-9]{1}|[.])$/i');
   $reemplazo = array('<b>$i</b>');
   $mag = preg_replace($buscarRegex, $reemplazo, $cadena);

   return $cadena;
}

$string = "1. Krewella - Can't Control Myself
2. Kdrew - Circles
3. Korn Feat. Skrillex & Kill The Noise - Narcissistic Cannibal
4. Netsky - Love Has Gone
5. Example - Midnight Run (Flux Pavilion Remix)
6. Madeon - Finale (Radio Version)
7. Feed Me Vs. Knife Party Vs. Skrillex - My Pink Reptile Party (Maluu's Slice'n'diced Mashup)
8. Krewella & Pegboard Nerds - This Is Not The End
9. Skrillex - Bangarang
10. The Prototypes - Suffocate
11. Ayah Marar - Mind Controller (Cutline Remix)
12. Skrillex Feat. Krewella - Breathe (Vocal Edit)
13. Utah Saints Vs. Drumsound & Bassline Smith - What Can You Do For Me (Tantrum Desire Remix)
14. Nero - Promises (Skrillex & Nero Remix)
15. 20 Florence & The Machine - Cosmic Love (Seven Lions Remix)";

echo reem2(nl2br($string));

?>
```

But it doesn't work, It doesn't change anything:

The output in HTML would be:

**1.** Krewella - Can't Control Myself

**2.** Kdrew - Circles

**3.** Korn Feat. Skrillex & Kill The Noise - Narcissistic Cannibal

**4.** Netsky - Love Has Gone

**5.** Example - Midnight Run (Flux Pavilion Remix)

**6.** Madeon - Finale (Radio Version)

**7.** Feed Me Vs. Knife Party Vs. Skrillex - My Pink Reptile Party (Maluu's Slice'n'diced Mashup)

**8.** Krewella & Pegboard Nerds - This Is Not The End

**9.** Skrillex - Bangarang

**10.** The Prototypes - Suffocate

**11.** Ayah Marar - Mind Controller (Cutline Remix)

**12.** Skrillex Feat. Krewella - Breathe (Vocal Edit)

**13.** Utah Saints Vs. Drumsound & Bassline Smith - What Can You Do For Me (Tantrum Desire Remix)

**14.** Nero - Promises (Skrillex & Nero Remix)

**15.** 20 Florence & The Machine - Cosmic Love (Seven Lions Remix)

What can I do?

Comment: What's the expected output ? There is too much going wrong here ...

Comment: I put the expected output, as you can see on the post.

Comment: +1 because I feel sorry for your neighbours :P

Comment: Bookmark this: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php It is useful for rapidly testing changes to regex syntax, separately from your php code.

Comment: @WillemRenzema or http://regex101.com :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following code:

```
function reem2($cadena) {
   $buscarRegex = array('/^(\d+\.)/mi'); // This means match any digit(s) followed by a dot at the beginning of each line. Note the m modifier
   $reemplazo = array('<b>$1</b>'); // replace should be with group 1, not some vague $i
   $mag = preg_replace($buscarRegex, $reemplazo, $cadena);
   return $mag; // return value: fixed
}
```

Comment: Useless `i` modifier (facepalm)

Comment: this will also require changing `echo reem2(nl2br($string));` to `echo nl2br(reem2($string));`

Comment: nl2br eats the trailing \n... so the ^ to match the beginning of the line would fail after the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is broken:

```
/^([0-9]{1}|[.])$/i
 ^-- start of line 
                ^--- end of line
```

you are allowing only for one SINGLE character on a line by itself, so the regex can never match anything.

You probably want something more like this:

```
/^([\d]+)\./
```

which will match any number of digits at the start of the line, which are followed by a single `.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return $cadena;
```

is your problem, Your doing the replace and then throwing the result away and returning the input

```
return $mag;
```

is probably what you meant

in fact your regex is also wrong

```
function reem2($cadena) {

   $buscarRegex = array('/^([0-9]{1,2}\.)(.*)$/m');
   $reemplazo = array('<b>\1</b>\2');
   $mag = preg_replace($buscarRegex, $reemplazo, $cadena);

   return $mag;
}
```

seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
function reem2($cadena) {

   $buscarRegex = array('/^([0-9]+\.)/m'); // changed modifier to multiline
   $reemplazo = array('<b>$1</b>'); // changed replacement to a capture offset
   return preg_replace($buscarRegex, $reemplazo, $cadena);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So from what I see, your regex is incorrect and you're returning the incorrect variable in function `reem2`, so try replacing your function with something like this

```
function reem2($cadena) {
    return preg_replace("/([0-9]+\.)/", "<b>$1</b>", $cadena);
}
```

Comment: Won't this match a single digit followed by one or more `.`'s